# Porqué tengo el error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exists si estoy usando el metodo paginate?

Tags: php, laravel

En mi AdminController estoy implementando la siguiente línea

```
$psicologos= Psychologist::paginate(10);
```

Luego estoy enviando a la vista la variable psicologos asi:

```
return view('admin.horarios', compact('psicologos'));
```

Y cuando voy a mi vista tengo lo siguiente

```
<div class="pagination">
  {{ $psicologos->links() }}
</div>
```

Lo loco es que en local me funciona y me salen los links de paginación, pero cuando lo subo al servidor obtengo el error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist señalando a la línea donde está { { $psicologos->links() } }

Porqué pasa ésto? A alguien más le ha pasado? Como lo han solucionado?

En mi AdminController estoy implementando la siguiente línea

```
$psicologos= Psychologist::paginate(10);
```

Luego estoy enviando a la vista la variable psicologos asi:

```
return view('admin.horarios', compact('psicologos'));
```

Y cuando voy a mi vista tengo lo siguiente

```
<div class="pagination">
  {{ $psicologos->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: no entiendo el codigo pareciera que faltan cosas ... pero no se entiende esta muy seccionado ...

Comment: haste el debug de $psicologos a ver que valores tiene antes de llegar a la vista ...